# List item can't be added using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I checked all the code and there is nothing wrong with it. When I check the "vegetables" radio button, write something in the text field and hit add, it doesn't add the element.

```js
function add() {
  var item;
  item = document.getElementById("item").value;
  if (document.getElementById("1").checked) {
    var li = document.createElement(li);
    text = document.createTextNode(item);
    li.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("1v").appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Welcome to your shopping List!</h1>
  <h2>Type in the item, choose its type, and hit add !!</h2>
  <div id="blue">
    <form action="">
      <label for="task">I need :</label><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Example : Apples" id="item" name="item"><br>
      <br>
      <label for="type">which is :</label><br>
      <div class="">
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="type" value="Vegetables">
        <label for="">Vegetables</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button id="add" onclick="add()">Add !</button>
</section>
</form>
</div>
<br>
<footer id="white">
  <div>
    <table border="bold">
      <th>Vegetables</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ol id="1v"></ol>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems:

- You are using a `form`, so when you click the `button`, the form
  submits and you leave the page. In your case, you aren't really going to submit data anywhere, so you really don't even need the `form` element or to specify `name` attributes for your fields.
- You don't have `li` in quotes, so you aren't actually creating an
  `<li>` element. Without quotes, the system thinks `li` is a variable, but since you don't have a variable called that, a new Global variable is created with a value of `undefined`, so your code executes as: `document.createElement("undefined")`, which does actually create: `<undefined></undefined>`, but since that isn't an actual HTML element, nothing is rendered for it, except the text you placed inside it (but no numbering):

```js
var li;
let el = document.createElement(li);

console.log(el);
```

- You are using `label` incorrectly. A `<label>` element correlates to a form-field element (i.e. `input`, `select`, `textarea`) as a way to have a "caption" for that element. To use it, you should set its `for` attribute to the `id` of the form-field its associated with or you can not use `for` and just nest the form-field its associated with inside of the `label`. `label` is not just for text you want to display.
- Your HTML is not nested properly and you are missing elements.
- Tables should really not be used for anything but displaying tabular
  data. They should not be used for layout. Since you are creating new
  ordered list items for each item added, you should not use a table.
  But, even when you do, you can't just have `th`. `th` must be inside
  of `tr`, which would then be inside of `thead`.
  A `footer` element is meant to provide "the fine print" content at the end of a section. Producing your list isn't that kind of content and shouldn't be in a `footer`.

Here's all of that put toghether:

```js
// Get your DOM references just once
const item = document.getElementById("item");
const list = document.getElementById("1v");
const veg = document.getElementById("type");

// Don't use inline HTML event attributes to set up events.
// Do your event binding in JavaScript, not HTML.
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", add);

function add() {
  if (veg.checked) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");  // <-- Need quotes around the element name
    li.textContent = item.value;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```css
table,th,td { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Welcome to your shopping List!</h1>
  <h2>Type in the item, choose its type, and hit add !!</h2>
  <div id="blue">
      I need : <input type="text" placeholder="Example : Apples" id="item"><br>
      <br>
      which is : <input type="checkbox" id="type" value="Vegetables"> Vegetables
      <div><button id="add">Add !</button></div>
  </div>
</section>
<br>
<footer id="white">
  <div>
    Vegetables
      <ol id="1v"></ol>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 quick fixes to your code (personally, I would rewrite the whole thing):

1. add `type="button"` to the button. It will prevent the button from defaulting to a `submit`.
2. Syntax error in `var li = document.createElement(li);`. the `li` should be in quotes:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
```